# What is the best way to generate youtube playlist rss feeds for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, youtube, rss

What is the best way to generate youtube playlist rss feeds for an iOS app?

At the moment I am using the following format:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/YOUR_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_NUMBER

But doesn't seem to be as widely compatible as other feed data urls I have used.

Answer (score 36):

Just used the following format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=YOUR_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_NUMBER
```

Make sure YOUR_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_NUMBER starts with 'PL'.

```
https://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=apIoMHXBxJ_KAfZL7re4ARls6wOC756q
```

or

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLapIoMHXBxJ_KAfZL7re4ARls6wOC756q
```

becomes

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PLapIoMHXBxJ_KAfZL7re4ARls6wOC756q
```

Comment: Make sure the playlist is not private though :)

Comment: Does YouTube always limit the entry count to 15? Is there a way to retrieve the "next page" of videos?

Comment: The "PL" requirement now returns a 404.

Comment: It works, but you only seem to get 15 items and what's worse, if the playlist is sorted with newer video's at the bottom (which I see very often), you'll never see them in the feed. This totally defeats the concept of a 'feed'.